# Issues with 'send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "A"), only works on Windows or Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pytest, sendkeys

I am working on an Automation Framework project (Pytest and Selenium), I and have several flows where I need edit data in forms, so the approach that we have been using is that we select the existing text (from the textbox or drop-down) using `Send Keys` and then just "clicking" *CONTROL + A*, and after that we use `Send Keys` as well to click the *Backspace* to delete the text and add the new one.

This works perfectly on Windows and Linux, but obviously it does not work on Mac computers, we thought about it when we implemented the solution, but we didn't have issues because everyone was using Windows computers (also the server in the CI).

I've been looking for solutions and it seems that there are lot of people with the same issue, but most the solutions do not work for everyone. I tried the following:

- Double clicking to select the text  --> didn't work
- Do not delete the text, just add new text to the existing one --> only works for textboxes, does not work for drop-downs.
- Detect the OS and with that use `Command` if it detects Mac and `Control` if it detects Windows or Linux --> but it didn't work.

I think that the main issue is that `Ctrl` does exist on Mac, but it does not work for selecting text, so it performs the action, but it doesn't do what we expect.

Is there a way to select text that will work on all OS, or is there a cleaner way to do it with Python?

Comment: What was the specific problem sending Cmd on macOS instead of Ctrl?

Comment: webelement has a "clear()" method.  You might want to try that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the problem is that the framework is using CTRL, but we have few people using Mac, so when they run the framework on their local, the 'editing' test cases fail. So I am looking for solution where the OS does not affect.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks, I tried that, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Sure, I understand why sending the wrong key could be a problem, I'm asking what the specific issue with your mentioned attempt to detect the OS and send the appropriate key was. Give a [mre] *of that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following if statement in the ***config.py*** file:

```
self.control_os = Keys.COMMAND if platform.system() == 'Darwin' else Keys.CONTROL
```